# Excel macro combine two Worksheet_Change code

Tags: vba, excel

I have two working Worksheet_Change code and I would like to use both of them on the same sheet. When I use them individually both of them work but when I use them together they do not. I tried to paste in two different codes but I got an ambiguous name detected error. I also tried to use elseif, next but none of them worked.
The two codes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("O:O"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 17).Value = Date
    End If
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 15 Then
        Range("P" & Target.Row).Value = Target.Value + Range("P" & Target.Row).Value
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just put both workshett Change events in the same sub

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Not Intersect(Range("O:O"), Target) Is Nothing Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 17).Value = Date
        End If

        If Target.Column = 15 Then
            Range("P" & Target.Row).Value = Target.Value + Range("P" & Target.Row).Value
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = ""
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Range("O:O"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cells(Target.Row, 17).Value = Date
        Range("P" & Target.Row).Value = Target.Value + Range("P" & Target.Row).Value
        Target.Value = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @AndrásKrämer Did you notice the difference between your accepted answer and the answer proposed by me? It should not be important for you if both the solutions are working, important is, what should be the correct way to handle event codes. There is too much for you to learn from the code I proposed if you want to write your next event code without taking any help. :)